# SQL 2012 SSIS Script Component Not Updating Table No Error

Tags: ssis

To get this down to the simplest form of my problem I created a table (dbo.testme) with two fields (f1,f2) and 7 records.

```
INSERT dbo.testme
    (f1 ,f2)
VALUES
    ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
,   ('old','Something old')
```

Using SSIS I want to update these records using an Transformation Script Component.

Here is the code in the Script Component...

```
Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
     Row.f1 = "new"
     Row.f2 = "Something new"
End Sub
```

I can see the new data in the data viewer (I would post a pic but since I am new it will not let me) but when I check the table nothing was updated.

Am I missing something here? I have to be doing something wrong, and it feels like one of those times chasing a missing ',' for a couple of hours.

Comment: Looks to me like you're just updating the rows in the dataflow.   I see no code that would update the table itself.

Comment: Add an OLEDB command shape and provide an UPDATE statement.